# Is there anyway to set custom icon for FloatingActionMenu on close and open?

Tags: android, icons, customization, floating-action-button

I have used FloatingActionMenu in my project with a GitHub library [link here](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button). But i can't customize icons of floating action menu on open and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can listen for click and maintain a boolean

```
boolean is_Expanded;
```

now on first click set

```
is_Expanded = !is_Expanded;
```

and

```
if(is_Expanded){
           fab.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable_expanded);
            }else{
           fab.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable_collapsed);
```

}